# Automounting Partitions Xubuntu

Tags: automount

I'm new to this Linux stuff and installed ubuntu but didn't really like the Unity setup and had some issues so switched to Xubuntu. However, I want my partitions to automount on boot. I tried using NTFS and PySDM or whatever it's called.

Any Help is GREATLY appreciated

Comment: what is the output of `gvfs-mount --list`

Answer (score 2):

This is a nice tutorial that explains Auto-mounting Windows Hard Drives:

[Ubuntu docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions) -  Note the hda1* is a Windows Partition

```
sudo fdisk -l

fdisk will print the partition tables of all your disks. The output from this command will look something like this;

Disk /dev/hda: 40.0 GB, 40013261856 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 4439 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/hda1 *         1             638      5124703  b   W95 FAT32
/dev/hda2           639           4525     31222327 83  Linux
/dev/hda3           4526          4635     497980   82  Linux swap
```